# How to setup a cgconfig.conf file to limit the cpu for all processes by a username to 10% of CPU?

Tags: linux, ssh, memory, cpu

For about 5 years now I have been wanting to limit the cpu of a user in CentOS(6) - without using cloudlinux.

So far, still have not been able to get an answer to this. cgroups seems to be a solution. However, I do not know how to set up the config file.

Here is a question which begins to answer it BUT DOES NOT ANSWER THIS QUESTION. I search again every few months but to no avail.
[How to limit an entire user to less than 10% of cpu, not just process?](https://superuser.com/questions/1112614/how-to-limit-an-entire-user-to-less-than-10-of-cpu-not-just-process)

I seriously need help setting this up as it is really needed.

---

**Here is what I got so far.**

I installed the service libcgroup `yum install libcgroup`.
I checked with `ls /cgroup` and verified it is installed. I get this output:
`blkio  cpu  cpuacct  cpuset  devices  freezer  memory  net_cls`

Now, I went to the `cgconfig.conf` file. This is located at `/etc/cgconfig.conf`

Underneath the `mount { ... }` section in the `cgconfig.conf` file, I added the following. I don't know if this is right (don't know if this does 10% of cpu).

I need some help finishing this up so I can finally restrict a user to desired percent of CPU (and, ideally, memory if possible!)

This is to create the group called `limitcpu` (although I actually want to call it limited group or something because I also want to restrict the memory as well, but for now let's just call it `limitcpu` group).

```
group limitcpu {

    cpu {
            cpu.shares = 200;
            # cpu.cfs_period_us
            # cpu.cfs_quota_us
    }
    memory {

    }
}
```

Then I am supposed to use this template:

```
template users/%g/%u {
                 cpuacct{
                 }
                 cpu {
                    cpu.shares = "1000";
                 }
      }
```

`%g` is supposed to be  group name.
`%u` is supposed to be username.

Ok so say my user that I want to limit is called `resourcehoggeruser`. How do I complete the above configuration to limit the CPU and emmory allocated to this user?

Should it look something like this?

```
template users/limitcpu/resourcehoggeruser {
                 cpuacct{
                 }
                 cpu {
                    cpu.shares = "1000";
                 }
      }
```

- What else do I need to get this working? Is the above even accurate code?
- Will this do what I want when the code is correct, which is to limit any processes ever spawned by the username to the desired percent of total CPU?
- Is this the correct location in the file to place this code?

What is a "share"? Say I have 16 CPUs and 24GB of RAM.

- What number do I put for `cpu.shares` if I want to have 10% of cpu?
- How about 20% of cpu?

How about memory?

- What code do I also use to limit memory to all processes by the user?
- If it uses something like I might guess, `mem.shares`, then what would be the "shares" for 10% of memory? How about 20% of memory?

I really appreciate your help! Thank you so much. I really need to get this working. I have searched long and hard and still can't find a clear answer so I really need your help.