# My Linux user cannot utilize 100% of all CPUs. (AI notebook, jupyter)

Tags: linux, cpu, utilization

I have access to the Linux account (named **jupyter**),
but when running certain commands, it cannot utilize all of the available CPUs. 
Once I switch to another user I can use all CPUs.

I use this command for tests:

```sh
for i in $(seq $(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN)); do yes > /dev/null & done
```

I'm checking CPU load with `htop`.

When I run this command on user **jupyter**,
I get a ***total*** of 98.6% CPU usage
(i.e., an average of 12.3% on each of eight CPUs).

```
Tasks: 45, 130 thr; 9 running
Load average: 1.67 0.94 0.38
Uptime: 00:05:38
         ︙
Mem[... 541M/31.4G]
```

[image: htop output]

    *Note: text has been manually transcribed from images.*

When I run this command on user **test1**,
I get 100.0% CPU usage on each CPU.

```
Tasks: 49, 130 thr; 9 running
Load average: 2.29 0.65 0.24
Uptime: 00:04:27
         ︙
Mem[... 552M/31.4G]
```

<sup>[[See image of text.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQVRz.png)]</sup>

User **jupyter** is default user for this notebook.

Any ideas?

Comment: Linux has some methods for limiting a users Cpu usage: https://superuser.com/questions/1112614/how-to-limit-an-entire-user-to-less-than-10-of-cpu-not-just-process

Comment: /etc/security/limits.conf is empty (all lines commented out with #), cpulimit not installed,  /etc/cgconfig.conf does not exist.

Comment: As it was jupyter notebook limitation was set in /lib/systemd/system/jupyter.service :-)

Answer (score 0):

Adding this for visibility.

The limit is set in

```
/lib/systemd/system/jupyter.service
```

**All credit goes to [Marian](https://superuser.com/users/1319791/marian)**